# Box.Net api display files and folders in ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, box-api

I am developing a Ruby on Rails app using box-api gem. I want to display box.net files and folders for a specific user. So far I have managed to authenticate a user and display his root files and folders. If I click on one folder, I want to display the content of that folder. So far, if I click on one folder, I save in params the folder_id, but I can't find the content of that specific folder.
So, if I know the folder_id how to get to that folder?
I tried something like this:

```
 account = Box::Account.new(BOXNET_KEY)
 account.authorize(auth_token: current_user.boxnet_auth_token)
 @account = account
 root = @account.root
 folder = root.folders[params[:folder_id].to_i]
```

Comment: Per the readme, the [box-api gem](https://github.com/box/box-ruby-sdk) is deprecated.  I would recommend using the actively developed [ruby gem](https://github.com/attachmentsme/ruby-box) from the attachments.me team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box-api gem is deprecated, they recommend you to use the [ruby-box](https://github.com/attachmentsme/ruby-box) API.

According to the documentation to list the files you need:

```
require 'ruby-box'

session = RubyBox::Session.new({
  client_id: 'your-client-id',
  client_secret: 'your-client-secret',
  access_token: 'access-token'
})

client = RubyBox::Client.new(session)
files = client.folder('/image_folder').files # all files in a folder.
folders = client.root_folder.folders # all folders in the root directory.
files_and_folders = client.folder('files').items # all files and folders in /files
```

First be sure you have the access token refreshed, as mentioned in the [Readme](https://github.com/attachmentsme/ruby-box).